Closing "meta" questions that will never have a good answer
Items such as How does psychiatry judge suicide by military and political leaders? - Psychology & Neuroscience Meta Stack Exchange continually get "bumped by community" in hopes of a better answer.
But when the question is "I've updated my question.  Can it be reopened now?", the question has been reopened, and the asker hasn't marked it as accepted, it's never going to get a better answer.
Should such questions be closed (or even deleted) to prevent the pointless bumping?

Interesting! Thank you for posting an answer to that meta question: I think that should prevent it from being bumped for now. But, your question is still valid: is this the right approach?

@StevenJeuris, except I posted that answer a month ago, and despite that, the question was bumped today.  Hence this item.

It never received an up vote before, so was considered not answered.

I closed it.
There are many "transactional" questions on meta, usually meant to get community or moderator attention for a specific issue that is then resolved.  The MSE suggests locking or closing such questions, or just leaving them as-is:

How do we (now) close meta questions that are no longer relevant?
What to do with meta questions referring to currently non-existing features?

